# i am trying get last two character of the String but i am getting error

Tags: java, string

```java
public String extraEnd(String str) {
    int len1=str.length()-2;
    int len2=str.length()-1;
    String s=str.charAt(len1)+str.charAt(len2);
    return s;
}
```

I am trying get last two character of the String but i am getting error like

> thisincompatible types: int cannot be converted to java.lang.String line:4

Comment: Because `char` + `char` will return an `int` value.

Comment: whta is inside your string ?

Comment: make your question more clear please and post your whole code

Answer (score 1):

You could just use `substring` for this:

```
public String extraEnd(String str) {
  if ( str.length() > 1){
    return str.substring(str.length() - 2);
  } else {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("String must contain at least 2 characters!");
  }
}
```

Comment: You might want to add a check that the string size is 2 or more

Comment: Thanks. Yes, the method should rather read `getLastTwoCharacters` in this case.